# http test will crash when attempting to send email in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I keeping getting an error response when the http test whenever the endpoint I am testing attempts to send an email.

public function testBasicTest ()
  {
    $faker = \Faker\Factory::create();

**http test**

```
$response = $this->json('POST', 'api/customRegister',
  [
    'name' => $faker->name,
    'email' => $faker->unique()->email,
    'password' => $faker->password
]);

error_log(json_encode($response->original,true));

$response->assertStatus(200);
```

}

**endpoint**

```
$when = Carbon\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1);

   \Mail::to($user)->later($when, new EmailConfirmation($user));
   \Mail::to('connorlloydmoore@gmail.com')->later($when, new EmailConfirmation($user));
```

here is all I have to go on in the response

> ords exception-message\"\u003EWhoops, looks like something went
>   wrong.\u003C/h1\u003E\n

Comment: What is your message error?

Comment: 003Cbody\u003E\n                    \u003Cdiv class=\"exception-summary\"\u003E\n                \u003Cdiv class=\"container\"\u003E\n                    \u003Cdiv class=\"exception-message-wrapper\"\u003E\n                        \u003Ch1 class=\"break-long-words exception-message\"\u003EWhoops, looks like something went wrong.\u003C\/h1\u003E\n

Comment: Put this information on the question.

Comment: Look at laravel log file.

Comment: you may get error message by adding to `app/Expeptions/Handler.php` to `render()` method: `if( app()->environment('testing') ) {   throw $exception; } ` . This way it will output exception in terminal. Do this and then add error message in your question